# PHPExcel fails on a heavy file import

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, phpexcel

I am trying to import excel files (xlsx) using PHPExcel library and store the data in a database. Following is my code:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/application/views/subfolder/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
$file_name = $_FILES['controlname']['tmp_name'];
$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$inputFileName = $file_name;
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
```

When I import a 1MB+ file having more than 1000 records, the code fails without returning any error with a strange behavior. However when I reupload that file by splitting it into multiple excels such that each excel contains only 1000 records, the same code works successfully.
To test, I tried echoing some message before and after the following line:

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

The message echoed before this line is printed, but the message written after this line does not work.

In order to allow heavy loads I have made settings of ini in MBs as well as GBs, but nothing works.

```
ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "100000000");
ini_set("max_allowed_packet ", "2G");
ini_set("max_execution_time ", "20000");
ini_set('max_input_time','20000');
ini_set('memory_limit', '2G');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','20M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '2G');
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Turn on all error reporting so you will see any errors that might be happening. `ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Strongly suggest upgrading to [PHPSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) the new and improved version of the deprecated PHPExcel.

Comment: @Dave Hi, the strange thing is that I dont see any errors but after adding the lines you suggested, things started working fine. This seems really confusing how and why this can happen.